# Android init replacement

Tags: android, init

I know that in the Android boot up sequence, after the Linux kernel boots up, it looks for `init`.

I replaced `init` with my custom C application `myapp`. In `myapp`, I wait for a user input for 5 seconds. If nothing is received, I want to run the original `init`, which I renamed as `init_original`. If I received user input, I wanna go on to do my stuff.

I placed my custom `init` and `init_original` in my unpacked ramdisk and cpio-ed and gzip-ed it according to instructions from http://android-dls.com/wiki/index.php?title=HOWTO:_Unpack%2C_Edit%2C_and_Re-Pack_Boot_Images

`init_original` is successfully called from my program using execve(). However, I get the following output:

```
[    3.851928] cpuidle: initiated for CPU0.
[    3.857116] cpuidle: initiated for CPU1.
[    3.862579] Freeing init memory: 320K

===============================================================================


Application started
Press enter in 1 second to enter test tool...
1 second is up, starting normal init

[    4.883422] init: /init.rc: 865: ignored duplicate definition of service 'ril-daemon'
[    8.247894] av8100_hdmi av8100_hdmi.3: HDMI display probed
[    9.694915] init: Timed out waiting for /dev/.coldboot_done
[    9.839630] init: cannot find '/system/bin/logwrapper', disabling 'cspsa'
[    9.847137] init: cannot execve('/system/bin/logwrapper'): No such file or directory
[    9.855102] init: /system/bin/logwrapper terminated with status 127.
[    9.869934] init: cannot find '/system/xbin/watchdog-kicker', disabling 'watchdog-kicker'
[    9.887695] init: cannot find '/system/bin/ifconfig', disabling 'shrm-netdev'
[    9.894836] init: cannot find '/system/bin/sh', disabling 'modem'
[    9.907714] init: cannot find '/system/bin/modem-supervisor', disabling 'modem-supervisor'
[    9.916015] init: cannot find '/system/bin/copsdaemon', disabling 'copsd'
[    9.922851] init: cannot find '/system/bin/cn_server', disabling 'cn_server'
[    9.929931] init: cannot find '/system/bin/simd', disabling 'simd'
....
```

Any idea what's wrong? Something to do with the way I call `init_original`, or the way I repacked the ramdisk.img, or something else?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the answer.

I did it the other way around, the original `init.c` is edited to call `myapp` instead.

In android's /system/core/init:`init.c`, I call `myapp` after the line

```
/* clear the umask */
umask(0);
// call program here
```

If `myapp` is called before `umask(0)`, the same errors shown aboe happen. I've no idea why it works this way though. If anyone can explain to me what `umask(0)` is doing (setting permissions or something like that I think) I will be grateful.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something very basic such as directing the output of a     `ls -l` or something similar to an output stream or file. Make this call from where you try to execute your own application to see if it has the proper file permissions to execute or not.

Using     `umask(0)` sets the file permission on the file that gets created by the user. It's like using     `chmod()` but doing before the file actually gets created. So in your case you're using     `umask(0)` which results into a     `'777'` file permission and so your application is able to run as it has the required file permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem,
in /sbin, ueventd and watchdogd are symlinks to ../init

so changing those: ln -s ../init_original and having myapp call init_original should work. =)